# SwiftUI: How to change visibility of details NavigationSplitView?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'd like to hide/show the details split view of a [`NavigationSplitView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview) on macOS.

However [`NavigationSplitViewVisibility`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitviewvisibility) does not seem to have such option. Changing [`.navigationSplitViewColumnWidth()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationsplitviewcolumnwidth(min:ideal:max:)) or `.frame()` has no effect on the details view although it works well with the content and list view.

```
 NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selection)
        } content: {
            content(for: selection)
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail")

 }
```

Did Apple forget to implement such a feature? :/

Comment: I don't think this design is common on Apple platforms; most apps just use an empty detail page. For example, the detail section of the Notes app is blank when there are no notes: https://imgur.com/bhu0RPT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to figure out an answer to the same question for myself, I have come to this conclusion:

A `NavigationSplitView` is meant to display a hierarchy where each next level (sidebar, content, detail) is a sub-level of of the previous one. In such a structure you might always want to show a detail view, even it is empty.

In any case, even if that is not the logic, the way to make the "detail" part hidable would be by implementing a two-column navigation with `NavigationSplitView` and adding a `DetailView`, enclosing all of these in an `HStack` and making the `DetailView` visibility conditional:

```
struct MyView: View {

@State var showingDetail: Bool = true

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        NavigationSplitView {
            SidebarView()
        } detail: {
            ContentView()
        }

        if  showingDetail {
            DetailView()
        }
    }
    .toolbar {
        Toggle(isOn: $showingDetail) {
            Image(systemName: "sidebar.trailing")
        }
        .toggleStyle(.button)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Great idea! HSplitView would be better than HStack, since width can be adjustable

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for iOS.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview

"At narrow size classes, such as on iPhone or Apple Watch, a navigation split view collapses into a single stack. Typically SwiftUI automatically chooses the view to show on top of this single stack, based on the content of the split view’s columns.
For custom navigation experiences, you can provide more information to help SwiftUI choose the right column. Create a State value of type NavigationSplitViewColumn. Then pass a Binding to that state to the appropriate initializer..."

```
@State private var preferredColumn = NavigationSplitViewColumn.detail

 NavigationSplitView(preferredCompactColumn: $preferredColumn) {
     List(selection: $selection)
 } content: {
     content(for: selection)
 } detail: {
     Text("Detail")
 }
```