# NavigationSplitView: Hide detail column in a three-column view

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationsplitview

I am creating a macOS app using SwiftUI, creating a three-column layout with `NavigationSplitView`. It seems that the sidebar (or first column, or leading column) is able to be hidden by default. I would like to have the option to hide the detail column (or third column, or trailing column) as well, which I have seen in many macOS apps (even in Xcode itself).
Apple's documentation only seems to have `NavigationSplitView` configuration to hide the sidebar or sidebar+content columns, but not detail column.

This is my current code, where I have created a toolbar button which hides the content of the detail view:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct NavigationView: View {
    @State private var detailViewVisible: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            Text("Sidebar")
        } content: {
            Text("Content")
        } detail: {
            if detailViewVisible {
                Text("Detail")
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                Button(action: {
                    detailViewVisible.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "sidebar.right")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This empties out the contents of the detail view column, but the column itself remains.

I have also tried setting the `width` of that column to `0`, which doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: I don't think you can hide the detail view but only one or both of the first two columns.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be part of the default configuration options, but seeing that I can hide it with the mouse by dragging its border all the way to the right, I was hoping there would be an easy way to do that programatically as well.

Comment: @muse-hemlock0m did you have resolve this problem? I want to only hide the content column(or second column), but I can't.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74140093/swiftui-how-to-change-visibility-of-details-navigationsplitview?rq=3

Comment: @muse-hemlock0m: side note: it's not a good idea to call your custom view "NavigationView", as this is already the name of an existing - albeit deprecated - SwiftUI view component.